# How can I select a pattern for bucket fill in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, patterns

When I select bucket fill I cannot find an option to select a pattern on GIMP 2.10.24

I remember being able to do this previously but can't do it now.

Does anyone know how to select a pattern for bucket fill?

Comment: It's in the tool options. [see here](https://imgur.com/KHZUAEf)

Comment: I'm not seeing tool options.  Maybe my view is off?

Comment: From the main menu, click on Windows > Dockable dialogs > Tool options.

Comment: Perfect.  I don't know why the dockable dialog disappeared but all good now.  Can you add as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Ok I've added it as an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the tool options. If the tool options aren't visible or if you accidentally closed them, then from the main menu click on:  *Windows > Dockable Dialogs > Tool Options*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way to change the current pattern if your Tool options dialog is not showing:  open the Patterns list dialog, either

- with `Windows ➤ Dockable dialogs ➤ Patterns`
- by clicking on the pattern preview in the toolbox (if showing, this is set with `Edit ➤ Preferences ➤ Interface ➤ Toolbox ➤ Appearance ➤ Show active brush, pattern and gradient`)